# Показать все обьекты из файла через swing

Tags: java, файлы, swing, объекты

Я пытаюсь сделать обработку файла с помощью swing. То есть показать весь файл,  удалить строку по фамилии, найти строку с помощью фамилии, записать все объекты с одного файла в другой. В общем 6 кнопок, одно поле для ввода и лист для отображения контента в файле.
Есть модель (Person) name, surname, lastname , date. Геттеры и сеттеры , конструктор.
 запись в файл:

```
Denis Maerov Olegovich 08.12.1994
Petrov Petya Petrovich 01.01.1999
aaaa aaaa aaa 11.11.1111
```

Кнопка которая должна отобразить содержимое файла , но после выбора файла ничего дальше не происходит.

```
JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
DefaultListModel<Person> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
...
JButton jButtonShowLastnames = new JButton("show file by lastname");
jButtonShowLastnames.getPreferredSize();
jButtonShowLastnames.setSize( 20, 20);
jButtonShowLastnames.setVisible(true);
jButtonShowLastnames.addActionListener ( new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String str = jTextField.getText();

        JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(jPanel);  <<<<---- застрял

        if (str.equals("")) {
            jTextField.setText("Type Here");
            jList.setModel(listModel);
            jTextField.setText("");
        }else {
            listModel.add(str);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Для получения выбранного файла используйте метод `getSelectedFile()` класса `JFileChooser`. Он возвращает выбранный файл в виде объекта `File`. Далее, зная, с каким файлом работать, вы сможете получить из него то, что вам нужно.